# JavaScript event to listen when text in DOM changes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events

I'm trying to get the subtotal of my cart (to access to the cart, you have to click in the top-right part of the screen from tecnosport.es).

To get the subtotal:

```
jQuery(".elementor-menu-cart__subtotal > .woocommerce-Price-amount > bdi");
```

Since I have three widgets, I get three elements, but you can see the value like this;

```
jQuery(".elementor-menu-cart__subtotal > .woocommerce-Price-amount > bdi").text();
```

**My goal:** When I add to cart some product, I want to listen if that subtotal changes to do something (for example, see it in the console via console.log).

**I tried but it isn't working:**

**1.** Since I get three elements, I should iterate them in a loop and listen the event:

```
jQuery(".elementor-menu-cart__subtotal > .woocommerce-Price-amount > bdi").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    jQuery(this).each(function( index ) {
        console.log("The content changed");
    });
});
```

**2.** I tried to change the order:

```
jQuery(".elementor-menu-cart__subtotal > .woocommerce-Price-amount > bdi").each(function( index ) {
    jQuery(this).bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
        console.log("The content changed");
    });
});
```

**One curious thing:** If for example I do this with some single element with ID (instead of three elements), it works perfectly. Am I iterating wrong? I am quite lost.

Comment: Check your selector *at the time your code runs*: `console.log(jQuery(".elementor-menu-cart__subtotal > .woocommerce-Price-amount > bdi").length)`  - it could be that the cart is generated after your code runs, so there's no elements to attach events to.  You might be able to attach the event to a parent element that *does* exist if the event bubbles.

Comment: [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent) are obsoleted, use [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.